# Index-Match with Multiple Criteria + Ranges

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I'm wanting to find a price, based of off a type and range.

For instance, here is a graph showing how much a specific fruit costs based on the amount purchased or type:

[image: Fruit Pricing Graph]

Here is what the worksheet would look like (TOP) and what the expect result would be (BOTTOM):

[image: Results]

I'm having an issue figuring out how to use a criteria and also a range.

If "Regular"- determine range and determine pricing

If "Organic" or "Import" - use set pricing

I tried using INDEX MATCH but am unable to figure out how exactly to work this. 
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Sorry to say but B1:H1 is just plain bad worksheet design if the labels are to be used for any type of lookup. Possible fix: retain the lower end of the range and use custom number formatting to display the upper end while discarding it from any calculation. e.g. `0\-\1\5\0` for 85-150.

Comment: Yeah, I realize this and is not set up that way, it was just for the example. Thanks for that tid bit though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change the top row of you data to only include the start of the range:

[image]

The use this INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Sheet4!$B$2:$H$4,MATCH(B2,Sheet4!$A$2:$A$4,0),IF(C2="Regular",MATCH(D2,Sheet4!$B$1:$F$1),MATCH(C2,Sheet4!$B$1:$H$1,0)))
```

Where 'Sheet4' is the name of the sheet with the data.

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, Thanks a ton @ScottCraner I really appreciate it!

Comment: What if I wanted to add another criteria column? For instance, having Local?

Comment: @Solomon3y would it be a fixed price or graduated like "Regular"?

Comment: Fixed price like organic and import

Comment: You could change the formula to `=INDEX(Sheet4!$A:$BB,MATCH(B2,Sheet4!$A:$A,0),IF(C2="Regular",MATCH(D2,Sheet4!$1:$1),MATCH(C2,Sheet4!$1:$1,0)))`  This will allow the range of data to expand.

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks a ton again @ScottCraner